# Eigen unaligned array assert

Tags: c++, eigen3

I have a class that finds the convex hull of a 2D set of points.  It contains a struct which has 2 `Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1>` inside.  It looks like this (with many things removed):

```
class Foo{
public:
    Foo(Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>);

private:
    struct edge{
        unsigned int a;
        unsigned int b;
        Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1> slope;
        double mag;
        Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1> normal;
        std::vector<unsigned int> list;
    };

    Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> points;
    std::vector<edge> edges
};
```

I am getting an assertion error when adding edges to the vector `edges` like this:

```
void Foo::DoThing(){
    edges.push_back(edge());
}
```

The exact error is:

> Assertion failed: (reinterpret_cast(array) & 0xf) == 0 &&
>   "this assertio n is explained here: "
>   "http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicUnalign
>   edArrayAssert.html" " **** READ THIS WEB PAGE !!! ****", file
>   \blah\blah\blah\includes\eigen\eigen-eigen-dc6cfdf9bcec\eigen\src\core\densestorage.h, line 86

I went to the webpage and read that I needed to add this macro:
`EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW` which I added to the struct as follows:

```
struct edge{
        unsigned int a;
        unsigned int b;
        Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1> slope;
        double mag;
        Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1> normal;
        std::vector<unsigned int> list;

        EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW
    };
```

But the error continues.  This is happening with VS 2013 and with Eigen version 3.2.9.  The same code unmodified works fine with version 3.2.0.  On linux with GCC version 5.3 it works fine with a beta build of Eigen.  What am I doing wrong with this newer version to cause this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `std::vector` that contains fixed-size Eigen types that are to be aligned. 
The issue is `std::vector<edge>` where `edge` contains fixed-size aligned `Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1>`.
Here, `EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW` is not sufficient, you additionally need to choose Eigen's aligned allocators as described in https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStlContainers.html

> Using STL containers on fixed-size vectorizable Eigen types, or classes >having members of such types, requires taking the following two steps:
>   (i) A 16-byte-aligned allocator must be used. Eigen does provide one ready for use: aligned_allocator.
>   (ii) If you want to use the *std::vector container, you need to `#include <Eigen/StdVector>`*.

You should correct your code roughly like this (not tested):

```
#include<Eigen/StdVector>
class Foo { 
  ...
  std::vector<edge,Eigen::aligned_allocator<edge> > edges;
}
```

Warning: On Linux you were just lucky it worked (maybe because 32bit/64bit), your code should really be corrected.

Comment: What's the difference between `Eigen::aligned_allocator<edge>` and `Eigen::aligned_allocator<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1> >` for this example?  The reason I ask is both produce code without errors.

Comment: Using an allocator made for a different type sounds like anything *could* happen at runtime, I would be careful.