# Is it dangerous to use the default Eigen::aligned_allocator for structures that contain Eigen types with fixed size?

Tags: eigen, eigen3

I found a few questions on the site that approach that subject, but none of them seem to do this directly. An example is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38883424/eigen-unaligned-array-assert/38890722#38890722), but the answer is not satisfying (it is untested, and doesn't explain why this is correct).

Consider this simple example:

```
class some_class
{
   public:
     Eigen::Matrix<double,3,4> M;
     std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<double,4,2>,
       Eigen::aligned_allocator<Eigen::Matrix<double,4,2>>> M2;

   //other stuff
};
```

Now assume that I need to declare an `std::vector` of `some_class` objects. Then, is the declaration

```
std::vector<some_class,Eigen::aligned_allocator<some_class>>>
//Note that it compiles and doesn't seem to cause noticeable run-time problems either
```

the correct way to do so, or do I have to reimplement an `aligned_allocator` for that class? I find the [documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStlContainers.html) a bit short and confusing, since it only states

> Using STL containers on fixed-size vectorizable Eigen types, or classes having members of such types requires ...

but it doesn't explicitly say whether one should write an `aligned_allocator` in such situations.

Is the declaration above safe or not, and why?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this question. This is exactly what this allocator is intended to be used for.

Comment: @chtz Yeah you're right, it's sort of absurd. I admit I haven't had time to go through the implementation of `aligned_allocator`, I think doing this should clear things up for me.